# Why useState doesn't work even though I load model in useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, next.js

I'm trying to load a TensorFlow.js model in a React component using the tf.loadLayersModel method, and then set the loaded model in the state of the component using the setState method. However, the state is not being updated and the component is not re-rendering.
I've tried calling setState inside the then callback of the promise returned by tf.loadLayersModel, but it doesn't seem to be working.

```
const [model, setModel] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        tf.loadLayersModel('/model.json')
            .then(loadedModel => {
                setModel(loadedModel);
                console.log('Model loaded', model);
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.error('Error loading model', err);
            });
    }, []);
```

Comment: This code looks fine, the error must be elsewhere.

Comment: If you're expecting `console.log('Model loaded', model);` to show the new model, it won't. But that normal and will not stop the component from rerendering.

Answer (score 0):

```
const [model, setModel] = useState(null);

useEffect(() => {
    tf.loadLayersModel('/model.json')
        .then(loadedModel => {
            setModel(loadedModel);
            console.log('Model loaded', model);
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.error('Error loading model', err);
        });
}, [model]);
```

You need to pass model to the Dependency array of useEffect